# C API for logging to logcat

Tags: android, c, logging, android-ndk

If I have an ELF binary written in C and compiled using an Android NDK, is there an API for logging messages so that they show up in logcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/logging).  This can be done by including

```
#include <android/log.h>
```

and calling

```
int __android_log_print(
  int prio,
  const char *tag,
  const char *fmt,
  ...
);
```

You can even set the default tag via

```
void __android_log_set_default_tag(
  const char *tag
);
```

This way, you can pull `NULL` as the tag in `__android_log_print`.

You'll have to add `-llog` to your linker flags.